# Is there a characterization of the topos of finite sets in the internal language?

Tags: lo.logic, topos-theory

The topos ${\mathcal{Set}}$, at least as axiomatized in ETCS, is a well-pointed topos that satisfies the axiom of choice and has a natural numbers object.

Is there a characterization of the topos ${\mathcal{FinSet}}$ in the internal language?

Comment: You could form an internal category whose externalisation is equivalent to the category of finite sets. Just do exactly what you would do in ordinary mathematics.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Characterization is too strong; there are many models of $\operatorname{ETCS}$, so its axioms don't characterize $\operatorname{Set}$ either.  But I'll interpret your question as asking how the axioms of $\operatorname{ETCS}$ might be changed if the intended model is $\operatorname{Fin}\operatorname{Set}$ instead of $\operatorname{Set}$.

Of course, you must remove the existence of the natural numbers object, and that might be sufficient; I mean, if you just want to have a topos whose internal mathematics is finitist in the weak sense that it doesn't assume the existence of any completed infinity, then this is sufficient.  Both $\operatorname{Fin}\operatorname{Set}$ and $\operatorname{Set}$ are models of this theory.

If you want to more assertively claim that the objects should be *finite* sets, then a strong way to do this is to add the following axiom scheme, where $\Phi$ is any property (in the language of $\operatorname{ETCS}$) of sets (objects):
$$ \Phi(0) \;\Rightarrow\; (\forall\,S\colon \operatorname{Ob},\; \Phi(S) \;\Rightarrow\; \Phi(S + 1)) \;\Rightarrow\; \forall\,S\colon \operatorname{Ob},\; \Phi(S) \text.$$
(Here I've chosen a particular way of phrasing the language of $\operatorname{ETCS}$ that hopefully makes sense to you.)

We can make this a finite axiomatization by requiring finiteness set by set:
$$ \forall\,X\colon \operatorname{Ob},\; \forall\,\mathcal{C}\colon \mathcal{P}\mathcal{P}X,\; \emptyset_X \in_{\mathcal{P}X} \mathcal{C} \;\Rightarrow\; (\forall\,S\colon \mathcal{P}S,\; \forall\,a\colon X,\; \neg\,(a \in_X S) \;\Rightarrow\; S \in_{\mathcal{P}X} \mathcal{C}\;\Rightarrow\; S \cup_X \{a\}_X \in_{\mathcal{P}X} \mathcal{C}) \;\Rightarrow\; \forall\,S\colon \mathcal{P}X,\; S \in_{\mathcal{P}X} \mathcal{C} \text{.}$$
This does induction over subsets of an arbitrary set $X$ rather than over sets themselves.  (Thanks to Ingo Blechschmidt for reminding me that this can be done!)  Actually, the clause $\neg\, (a \in_X S)$ can be omitted, giving an a priori weaker axiom (Kuratowski finiteness), which is equivalent in a boolean topos.

The axiom scheme proves the above axiom, but I haven't gone through all of the sentences of $\operatorname{ETCS}$ to see if the axiom proves each instance of the axiom scheme.  (Offhand, I'd guess not.)

Comment: It seems that if $X$ is a discrete space, then the topos of sheaves over $X$ satisfies ${\mathsf{ETCS}}$ minus the existence of the natural numbers object.

Comment: No, any topos of sheaves has a natural numbers object (which is always the constant sheaf at the set of natural numbers).

Comment: Toby: Couldn't you also add axioms expressing that any object is Kuratowski-finite and discrete? This seems to me to not require an axiom scheme (it does require unbounded quantification).

Comment: @IngoBlechschmidt :  That's a good idea; I don't know why I didn't do that!  And it only requires quantification over double power objects, which is fine in a topos.

Comment: @user2529 :  I'm not sure what I was saying in my comment from 2013.  That the topos of sheaves over a discrete space has a natural-numbers object shows that it satisfies ETCS, not just ETCS without a natural-numbers object.  But it does still satisfy the latter (although it doesn't satisfy the stronger version where we add axioms to make every set finite).